# Control placement of dynamically inserted div

Tags: html, css

I have a page into which a div is dynamically inserted by some 3rd party javascript code. I want the div to be placed inside another div but I cannot control its insertion. Right now it is being placed below the footer. Is there anyway to get it in the right location (inside the main-container div)? Below is the code and the fiddle...

```
<body>
<div id="header-nav">
    Some header stuff
</div>

<div id="main-container">
    This is where my div belongs
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Some footer stuff
</div>
<!-- this part is dynamically inserted when the page loads  -->
<div id="mydiv"> 
    I was inserted here but it is not my home
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jjaleel/h3d2j7yx/

I am able to override the css of mydiv on page, could I use that or some other css solution to put in the right place?

Comment: Add the java script to the fiddle. We need to see what is really happening

Comment: Haha well without seeing the JavaScript that's inserting it, it's kind of hard to troubleshoot or test.

Comment: Please check the check mark for my answer as it does exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code. Added a border so you could see it was working.

http://jsfiddle.net/h3d2j7yx/1/

```
<body>
    <div id="header-nav">
        Some header stuff
    </div>

    <div id="main-container" style="border:1px solid black;">
        This is where my div belongs
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Some footer stuff
    </div>

    <div id="mydiv"> 
        I was inserted here but it is not my home
    </div>
</body>

<script>

//Call the function to grab the div and insert it into the main div    
test();

function test() {
if( document.getElementById('mydiv') != "undefined")
    {
    var element = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    document.getElementById('main-container').appendChild(element);
       }       
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your suggestion is much appreciated but it doesn't completely solve my problem, please see my response to Saumil below. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, please explain what my example does not solve.

Comment: I get the error Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object. document.getElementById('main-container').appendChild(element); because the mydiv element does not seem to exist when the script fires. I am guessing because it has not been inserted yet by the 3rd party js.

Comment: Take a look now. Checking if the div exists to prevent error. You may need to trigger the function after the third party script is loaded. I'll add it tomorrow if this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control the placement of the div, you can place it anywhere you want after it is placed.

Include the below script in your page,

```
function moveDiv(){
    var newDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var parent = document.getElementById("header-nav");
    parent.appendChild(newDiv);
}
moveDiv();
```

Substitute "header-nav" with the element's id where you want to append the dynamically created div.

One important thing to consider here is that **the above script should be placed below the 3rd party javascript which is generating the dynamic div,** because if this script is executed before the 3rd party script then it may not find the element having `id="mydiv"` as it is generated by the 3rd party javascript.

Comment: I think you are right in your last point, but no matter where on the page I place your script, I keep getting the error TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object. document.getElementById('main-container').appendChild(element); So it seems our script is always firing before the 3rd party inserts that div. Is there any way to force it fire after?

Comment: @user3223841 The above script is firing first probably because it is written within the HTML page and your 3rd party script is an external script. What you can do is create another external JS file and copy down the above script in it. While importing, make sure the 3rd party script is imported before your newly created external file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting using javascript, always do what works best with javascript. So for example we can create an element like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV"); //creates a javscript DIV element
div.className("dynamic-div"); //sets a class name <div class="dynamic-div">
div.innerHTML = "This is a div, but is not my home or whatever"; //add some text
document.body.appendChild(div); //adds the javascript element as an HTML element
```

and then we can have pre loaded CSS:

```
.dynamic-div {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

remember that the CSS will load, but as soon as the element is displayed on the screen, the CSS will take action and format everything just the way you want.

so one the function is called and the DIV is added with the defined classname, the CSS will take over and format the object the way you want it to. Just always have the CSS already loaded. It provides:

- Less javascript work
- A lot faster
- Will only be used if/once needed
- Already ready to use at startup